# Update multiple colums into one column as string

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I would like to update multiple colums into one column of an another table:

Table 1:

Num | ColumnA  |   ColumnB |

1       | Peter         |  Mueller     |

1       | Jonny        | Corleone   |

2       | John          | Cohn          |

1       | Sarah         |     Wood     |

Now I want to update  ColumnA and ColumnB into ColumA of Table2 like this:

Table2:

Num | ColumnC  |

1       | Peter, Mueller, Jonny, Corleone, Sarah, Wood |

2       | John, Cohn |

Thanks in advance

Machupicchu

Comment: so which is it... sql server or MySQL... the 2 are not the same. Pick one

Comment: Don't do this, comma separated value columns are hard to query and index

Comment: I Will need it as string for a letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO Table2(NUM, Columnc)
SELECT num, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(columna,',',columnb)) name
FROM table1
group by num
```

Here a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a62cb/2)

Comment: Good. Can you mask this as the answer?